# Hashi Vault secrets directory

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I am working with Hashi Vault and brought up a vault server with the storage backend "file" to be a directory in the config file.

```
storage "file" {
   path = "/home/ubuntu/vaultdata"
  }
```

When I write a secret using the "vault write" command, where is the secret written in that directory /home/ubuntu/vaultdata ?

Comment: Looks like the logical directory inside of it might be the place ? I see this when I ls :  ls vaultdata/logical/
3d327743-6164-0b0e-8b7c-853b2f78202f

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct mapping between files in filesystem storage backend directory and vault secrets.

Among other reasons, this is done for security one. For example, if talking about KV secret engine, this prevents discovering the existing keys in Vault by analyzing the backend storage directory.

---

If you want to achive something like FUSE filesystem, there are no plans for such support in Vault team, accordingly to [github/issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/110). But they suggest trying a [vaultfs](https://github.com/asteris-llc/vaultfs)  to achive this.

Comment: So in case of the KV secrets engine, what is stored in the backend storage directory ? And. what about in case of AWS secrets engine when the backend storage is an AWS bucket ? The access key and secret key are returned back to the client in case of AWS. What is stored in the storage backend ?

Comment: take a look at this link- https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/storage/filesystem.html.  What is it referring to by 'Vaults data' when it says the storage backend stores Vaults data ? I assume that data meant the secrets the Vaults secrets engine generate. Can you help clarify ?  Also some information in this link saying that keys/value secrets are stored in Vault (which I assume is the backend storage) - https://www.vaultproject.io/intro/